# SlowCheetah placing settings in app.config.deploy and not .exe.config

Tags: wpf, clickonce, slowcheetah

I'm using the latest version of SlowCheetah on an existing WPF project I have that was already using ClickOnce.

I'm trying to provide different application settings (the applicationSettings node in app.config; the ones that form the Settings.settings file) for each environment. When I publish I'm getting a app.config.deploy (with the correctly transformed settings inside) and also a ProjectName.exe.config file that doesn't have transformed settings.

When someone installs the application and runs it, it's just using the settings inside ProjectName.exe.config (which is correct) and obviously the transformed settings in app.config are ignored. Is there an extra step to get SlowCheetah to put the transformed settings into the exe.config instead?

Comment: I think it may be related to this issue:

https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/87